# Use Restrict method to get recipient, subject and date range

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-filter

I tried

```
'only works for name, not email address.
"@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:displayto"" ci_phrasematch '%John Doe%'" 

'works great, failed when use AND. today was declared as string
"@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:subject"" like '%" & emailSubject & "%'"

'works great, failed when use AND. today was declared as string
"[ReceivedTime] <= today"
```

How can I use `Item.Restrict` to filter the recipient email address, subject and date range together?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:4539709+[outlook-filter]

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is example for multiple filters*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim TargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String

    Set olNs = Application.Session
    If TargetFolder Is Nothing Then Set TargetFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    Debug.Print TargetFolder.Name

    Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                       Chr(34) & " >= '01/10/2018' And " & _
                       Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                       Chr(34) & " < '01/16/2018' And " & _
                       Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & _
                       Chr(34) & "Like '%0m3r 0m3r%'"

    Set Items = TargetFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is mailitem Then
            Set Item = Items(i)
            Debug.Print Item.Subject
            Debug.Print Item.ReceivedTime
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

**`If TargetFolder Is Nothing Then Set TargetFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`**

> [Returns or sets a MAPIFolder object that represents the current folder displayed in the explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211818(v=office.11).aspx)
>
> ---

Or use

```
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim TargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set TargetFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

Filter with Subject line

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                   Chr(34) & " >= '01/10/2018' And " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" & _
                   Chr(34) & " < '01/17/2018' And " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromname" & _
                   Chr(34) & "Like '%0m3r 0m3r%' And " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   Chr(34) & " Like '%Bla Bla%'"
```

Comment: Hi, why is it returning `Inbox`? shouldn't it also print out the `Subject` and `ReceivedTime`? I modify `"Like '%0m3r 0m3r%'"` to my name. I did sent myself a mail yesterday. The `Items.Count` was 0.

Comment: @ppz `fromname` should be name from sender - `TargetFolder ` will return Current active folder, the folder your viewing -

Comment: Yes. I was testing using subject as well. It does print out the relevance data. However, once I include the Date filters. It's returning empty result. I'm checking for the date format

Comment: Ok, get It. It's because my system date format is not in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I modify the date format and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not know what "today" is. You need to provide a suitably formatted date value, e.g. "2018-01-17"