# Why does loop in email inbox from latest email skip files?

Tags: vba, loops, outlook

I am trying to download the email attachments in Outlook inbox based on received date. My code downloads attachments, however it skips files.

For example: I was trying to loop the email from the latest email (Received date:01/14/2019). After looping around 10-15 emails, it suddenly jumps to read the email received on 12/07/2018.

```
Sub saveemailattachment()

'Application setup
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Set ONS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olfolder As Outlook.Folder
Set olfolder = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olmail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim olattachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim i As Long
Dim filename As String
Dim VAR As Date

'Loop through all item in Inbox
For i = olfolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards

    Set olmail = olfolder.Items(i)

    For Each olmail In olfolder

        VAR = Format(olmail.ReceivedTime, "MM/DD/YYYY")
        filename = olmail.Subject

        If VAR = "1/14/2019" Then  
            For Each olattachment In olmail.Attachments
                olattachment.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\Rui_Gaalh\Desktop\Email attachment\" & olattachment.filename
            Next

        Else

        End If

        'Mark email as read
        olmail.UnRead = False
        DoEvents
        olmail.Save
    Next
Next

MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `For Each olmail In olfolder` I'm not sure why you have there.

Comment: I do not understand how this finds any emails received today. For an email received on 14 January, 2019, `VAR = Format(olmail.ReceivedTime, "MM/DD/YYYY")` will set `VAR` to 01/14/2019 which is not equal to 1/14/2019.  I would have something like: `Dim Midnight As Date` `Midnight = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))` This sets `Midnight` to time 0:00:00 for today. `olmail.ReceivedTime >= Midnight` will be True for all today's emails.

Comment: Let me know if you are still having trouble

Answer (score 0):

*If you are just trying to save Email Attachments that was received on "1/14/2019" then No need for*

> ```
> For Each olmail In olfolder
>
> Next
> ```

*When you are already using*

> ```
> For i = olfolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
>
> next
> ```

*Here is another one `objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)`?? remove it, also `Dim olmail as a generic Object` - there are objects other than MailItem in your Inbox.*

> ```
> Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
> Set olmail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
> ```

*Set `olMail` with in the loop then check if the olMail is `MailItem`*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Sub saveemailattachment()
    'Application setup
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

    Dim ONS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ONS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set olfolder = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim olmail As Object

    Dim olattachment As Outlook.attachment
    Dim i As Long
    Dim filename As String
    Dim VAR As Date


    'Loop through all item in Inbox
    For i = olfolder.items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
        DoEvents
        Set olmail = olfolder.items(i)

        If TypeOf olmail Is Outlook.MailItem Then

            VAR = Format(olmail.ReceivedTime, "MM/DD/YYYY")
            filename = olmail.Subject

            If VAR = "1/14/2019" Then

                For Each olattachment In olmail.Attachments

                    olattachment.SaveAsFile _
                    "C:\Users\Rui_Gaalh\Desktop\Email attachment\" _ 
                            & olattachment.filename

                Next
                'Mark email as read
                olmail.UnRead = False
            End If
        End If

    Next

    MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```

*You should also look into `Items.Restrict` method*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48311864/4539709

---

> <sub>*[Items.Restrict method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396http://) is an alternative to using the Find method or FindNext method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The Find or FindNext methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The Restrict method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.*</sub>

---

> <sub>[Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867646.aspx#String%20Comparisons%20Using%20DASL%20Syntax) that DASL filters support includes equivalence, prefix, phrase, and substring matching. Note that when you filter on the Subject property, prefixes such as "RE: " and "FW: " are ignored.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop through all items in a folder - some folders can have ten of thousands of messages. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like `"[ReceivedTime] >= '2019-01-14' AND [ReceivedTime] < '2019-01-15'"`.

In case of `Items.Find/FindNext`, you won't have a problem with skipped emails. In case of `Items.Restrict`, use a down loop from count down to 1 step -1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions. The code works perfectly. Please find the final code below:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub saveemailattachment()

    'Application setup
     Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
     Set objOL = New Outlook.Application

    Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
    Set ONS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set olfolder = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim olmail As Object

    Dim olattachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim i As Long
    Dim InboxMsg As Object
    Dim filename As String


    'Set variables
    Dim Sunday As Date
    Dim Monday As Date
    Dim Savefolder As String

    Dim VAR As Date
    Dim Timestamp As String

    Monday = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2")
    Sunday = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3")
    Savefolder = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4")

'Loop through all item in Inbox
For i = olfolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
    DoEvents
    Set olmail = olfolder.Items(i)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


        'Check if olmail is emailitem
        If TypeOf olmail Is Outlook.MailItem Then

               'Set time fram
                VAR = olmail.ReceivedTime 'Set Received time
                Timestamp = Format(olmail.ReceivedTime, "YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss") 'Set timestamp format


                If VAR <= Sunday And VAR >= Monday Then


                    For Each olattachment In olmail.Attachments
                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


                    'Download excel file and non-L10 file only
                    If (Right(olattachment.filename, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(olattachment.filename, 3) = "xls")Then

                        'Set file name
                        filename = Timestamp & "_" & olattachment.filename

                        'Download email
                        olattachment.SaveAsFile Savefolder & "\" & filename

                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

                        End If
                    Next


                Else

                End If

                'Mark email as read
                olmail.UnRead = False
                DoEvents
                olmail.Save

    Else
    End If
Next


MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```